# Python CSV how to remove first row of data?

Tags: python, csv, row

I want to store some values from the loop, at the same time in this loop i want to remove first row.

From my code, i created a tester.csv file from start, and wrote in 10 rows different type of numbers just for keeping records stored from loop in 10 rows continuously.

Here is my code just for storing the data from loop:

```
import csv

x = 1
while True:
    print (x)
    with open("tester.csv", "a",  newline='') as f:
        thewriter = csv.writer(f)
        thewriter.writerow([x])
    x += 1
```

I expect:

the data to be stored in user defined rows number ( Like after 11 recorded rows, delete the first one and then record the new one, in a loop like that ).

So insted of storing all this rows:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I want to keep the loop and store the data while deleting the first row, by this keeping the data in max 5 rows:

```
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: please can you provide the wanted output as an example

Comment: @nassim Here you go!

Answer (score 0):

you must open the file in 'w+' mode instead of 'a' and use fseek to go to the beginning of the file.

```
import csv

x = 1
with open('test.csv', 'w+', newline="") as f:        
    w = csv.writer(f)
    while x < 15:
        print(x)    
        if x == 10:
            f.seek(0,0)        
        w.writerow([x])
        x += 1
```

Comment: Doesn't work ! From your code, in test.csv it stores some random numbers, and stops at 15 rows ! 
I need: The loop of increasing numbers to continue but to store only the last like 10 rows of numbers.

Comment: Sure you need to replace the while condition.

Comment: The main point is to open file in W+ mode and use fseek to get back to the start of the file

Comment: It seems that you try to delete rows that are == to number 10...But i need somehow to delete the first row after there are more than 10 rows  !